# Can I create a two-column layout that fluidly adapts to narrow windows?

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to design a page that has two columns of content, div#left and div#right. (I know these aren't proper semantic identifiers, but it makes explaining easier) The widths of both columns are fixed.
[image: Desired result - wide viewport]
*Desired result - Wide viewport*

When the viewport is too narrow to display both side-by-side, *I want #right to be stacked on top of #left*, like this:
[image: Desired result - narrow viewport]
*Desired result - narrow viewport*

My first thought was simply to apply `float: left` to #left and `float: right` to #right, but that makes #right *attach* itself to the right side of the window (which is the proper behavior for `float`, after all), leaving an empty space. This also leaves a big gap between the columns when the browser window is really wide.
[image: Opposite floats]
*Wrong - div#right is not flush with the left side of the viewport*

Applying `float: left` to **both** divs would result in the wrong one moving to the bottom when the window was too small.
[image: Wrong one on top]
*Wrong - div#right is not on top of div#left*

I could probably do this with media queries, but IE doesn't support those until version 9. The source order is unimportant, but I need something that works in IE7 minimum. Is this possible to do without resorting to Javascript?

Comment: I was going to sugest float:left for both but I re-read your requirement that #right be first. oops

Comment: And floating both right would result in a large gap at left when the screen is wide, is that the problem with that?

Comment: @JMC Creative: That's correct.

Comment: I don't see it w/out javascript that checks for the viewport width and appropriately assigns class/attributes.  Good challenge though!

Comment: The gap is a result of the div floating to the right in a space that is wider that the width of the div.

Comment: +1 for freehand ellipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you pretty close (disclaimer: I only tested it in Chrome and Firefox), using CSS only:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.main1{ width: 40%; 
    min-width:200px;
     height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.main2{ width: 40%; 
    min-width:200px;
     height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    float:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main1">right div</div>
<div class="main2">left div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick is the inline-block display style... Someone else might be able to build on this and do better, but I think it's close.

Aerik

Comment: inline-block have some bugs while using in IE6/7 and it's not working at all in FF2

Comment: I have none of those browsers to test and the answer does provide a javascript-less solution for the most recent browsers.  This article seems to suggest a IE7 solution is possible: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/ but I do not have IE7 to try it out.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because the technique (`inline-blocks` with the second one `floated` left) comes closest to working the way I want, and I've given up hope of IE7 support (without JS) at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Add an outer container to the 2 columns which is floated left, but without a specific width.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/ExjU2/).

Comment: Cool. Is there any way to get rid of the gap on the left side, though?

Comment: I think you'll have to use JS. Without it you'll alwas have gaps

Comment: Yeah with JS you could set the width of the outer container to the width of the right column when the screen is resized below a certain threshold.  that would eliminate the space to the left.

Comment: The question is "without resorting to javascript"

Comment: It is, but if there's no other way around it, I'm willing to compromise. :)

Comment: @JMC Creative : I know was augmenting your css only solution with what has to be done in JS to eliminate the space.  That is why I put in a comment not an answer (=

Comment: Could you clobber the gap on the left by having a dummy element to the right of the container which has width *, which will then soak up any available space on the right, leaving no space on the left? Or how about a third element inside the container doing the same?

Comment: @anton & @Brant okay, sorry, you guys are right. I kept working with the solution in the fiddle, but I don't think it's getting better than that with css alone...

Comment: @Tom If you can do it, I would _love_ to see it.  I've bit hitting that thing until my eyes are numb.

Comment: @JMC Creative: i had a quick go, and my attempts looked like the futile scrawlings of a particularly slow toddler. I can make extra divs appear in all sorts of surprising places, but not where we need one.

Comment: If the columns are different widths then the alignment is still incorrect, even if I were to use a bit of JS to reduce the width of the wrapper. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExjU2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    /*html body { height:100%; }*/

    #left { width: 500px; margin: 0 6px 0 6px; background-color:Blue; }
    #right { width: 500px; margin: 0 6px 0 6px; background-color: Orange; }
    #container { width: 1024px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        setUpFloats();

        $(window).bind("resize", setUpFloats);
    });

    function setUpFloats() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
            $('#container').css('width', $('#right').width());
            $('#container').css('padding-left', '12px');
        } else {
            $('#container').css('width', 1024);
            $('#container').css('padding', '0');
        }
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container" style="float:left;">
    <div id="right" style="float:right;">right</div>
    <div id="left" style="float:right;">left</div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I fixed it so the orange (right) is on top.  silly me got confused which image was right.

**EDIT 2**

Fixing padding

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It's the way HTML works (or does not work :P ).

At least not a way I know of.

You'll always have space at the left side I guess.

I'll try some things though and let you know if I find something.